# cutting off string after last word in dynamic url

Tags: javascript, regex

what I'm trying to do is:

www.test.de/testA/testB/testC/cutoff/testD/testE

I need to cutoff the string right after "cutoff".
The link will change quiet often, so I need do to something like:

regexp = /cutoff/i  (everything which comes after this)
window.location = regexp;

The link does also change at the beginning, therefore it is not possible to count the char and replace it then.

Thank you for any answer given to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything up until cutoff/?

`/.*cutoff\//`

Edit: Here's the JS

```
var s = 'www.test.de/testA/testB/testC/cutoff/testD/testE';
var x = s.replace(/(.*cutoff\/).*/, '$1');
window.location = x;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6F44a/

Comment: So i guess it would be

var s = window.location
var x = s.replace(/(.*cutoff\/).*/, '$1');
window.location = x

?

or how can I get the url at first? :)

Comment: could you please explain what '$1' does in replace?

Answer (score 0):

Is this too simple a solution?

```
var s = "www.test.de/testA/testB/testC/cutoff/testD/testE"
var re = /(.+cutoff)/i
s.replace(re, "")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var reg = new RegExp( "([.\/]*\/" + cutoff + "\/)." , 'i' );
window.location = window.location.replace( reg , "$1" );
```